# Show there exists a unique solution to $-u''(x)+\lambda \int^1_0 \sin(u(y))dy =f(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory

Let $\lambda\in (-1,1)$.  Show that for every $f\in C[0,1]$ there exists a unique solution $u\in C[0,1]$ to

$$-u''(x)+\lambda \int^1_0 \sin(u(y))dy =f(x)$$

With $u(0)=u'(1)=0$.

My work thus far:

$$\langle Lu,v \rangle = \int^1_0 -u''(x)v(x)dx+ \lambda \int^1_0 \sin(u(y))dy\int^1_0 v(x)dx $$

Using IBP, we find $v'(1)=0$, $v(0)=0$, and

$$\langle Lu,v \rangle = \int^1_0 u(x)(-v''(x))dx+\lambda\int^1_0 \sin(u(y))dy\int^1_0 v(x)dx $$

So what is the adjoint operator $L^*$? Orevious experience tempts me to say $L^*v=-v''$

If this is the case $N(L^*)=\left\{0\right\}$, so that there is always a solution to $Lu=f$.

For uniqueness, 
Let $\lambda=0$. Then $-u''=0$ implies $u=0$ so the solution will be unique.

Let $\lambda\neq 0$. Then boundary conditions tell us

$$-u''(x)+\lambda c =0 \implies u(x)=(x^2-x)\frac{\lambda c}{2}$$

So the question becomes, is there a nonzero $c$ that satisfies

$$-\lambda c+\lambda \int^1_0 \sin\left((y^2-y)\frac{\lambda c}{2} \right)dy =0  $$

Uhh.....?

Comment: Numerically its easy to see that the answer is yes, but only for certain values of $\lambda$: $\lambda \leq -12$ or $\lambda \gtrsim 150$ (roughly). The lower bound (for $\lambda < 0$) can be established by using the inequality $\sin x \leq x$.

Comment: It is assumed $\lambda\in (-1,1)$

Comment: Then it easy. Observe that since $|\sin(x)|\leq x$ then if a solution exist then $c \in (-1,1)$. Now we can do an infinite decent to show $c=0$ is the only solution. Since $(y-y^2) \leq \frac{1}{4}$ for $y\in [0,1]$ the argument of the sine-function is less than $\frac{1}{8}$ and therefore the integral and $|c| \leq \frac{1}{8}$. The same argument using $|c| \leq 1/8$ gives $|c| \leq \frac{1}{8^2}$ and again gives $|c| \leq \frac{1}{8^3}$ etc.

Comment: btw an easier way to show this is to observe that $|c| = \left|\int_0^1\sin(\cdot )dy\right| < \frac{|\lambda| |c|}{8}$ which implies $|\lambda| > 8$. Thus no solutions for $|\lambda| \leq 1$ except for $\lambda = 0$.